# How to include/Build Glide library for eclipse?

Tags: android, image-loading, android-glide

When i start looking for Image loading libraries for android then i found Picasso and Glide are much better then other libraries . I can integrate Picasso with eclipse but there is no document related to how use Glide library in eclipse for android project.

Reference: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

**FYI:** There is notes about building Glide with Intellij IDEA.

Comment: I know you might not like this comment but: Android Studio 1.0 got released, and Gradle is definitely the way Android went. Maybe time to migrate over Android Studio 1.0 and Gradle 1.0.0 ?

Comment: I think you mean Gradle 2.2.1 and Android Gradle Plugin 1.0.0?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Maven in your project, you can try this (but you probable saw this already):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.bumptech.glide</groupId>
  <artifactId>glide</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Or you can download the jar directly from [maven](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.bumptech.glide%7Cglide%7C3.4.0%7Cjar) (at the bottom of the page) and include it in your project.

Comment: currently i'm using eclipse only in which i'm not using maven.

Comment: You can try my second option then. You don't need Maven for it.